# Will a Lenovo X220i with i3 support either 1066/1333?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

Looking at this page https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53438/intel-core-i3-2350m-processor-3m-cache-2-30-ghz.html It mentions that 16GB of memory is supported but then it says "dependent on memory type". Are they referring to the speed of the memory or the manufacturer?

Has anyone put 16GB in a Lenovo x220i i3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dependent on memory type" is just a standard disclaimer, it does not apply here. The phrase applies e.g. to CPUs that support both UDIMM and RDIMM, with the latter enabling higher total memory capacity. It does not refer to memory speed.

A better source for information on Thinkpads is https://thinkwiki.de/X220
It's in German, but the memory section states that 16GB will work in an X220, using two 8GB DIMMs.
And I have seen quite a few reports from people using 2x8GB in an X220.

Comment: I have, it worked.